# How to use request.env in before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter, before-save

I want to check some field before save and change it into default browser language.

I want to use before_save filter:

```
def update
 @website = Website.find(params[:id])
  if @website.language == "Automatic (by user's browser language)"
   @website.language = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
 end
respond_to do |format|
  if @website.update_attributes(params[:website])
    format.html { redirect_to @website, 
      notice: 'Note: code has been updated. Please replace the code you have on your website with the code below. Only then changes will take effect.'}
    format.js
   end
  end
end
```

**I need to check:**

```
  if @website.language == "Automatic (by user's browser language)"
    @website.language = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
 end
```

And it works in create action, but not in update.

How can I do this ?

Comment: request object can't be access in model directly

Comment: So how I can control what user selects ? I will post my update action.

Answer (score 1):

Before save is used in model and request is usually not available in model.

However if you really want to do it there, check: http://m.onkey.org/how-to-access-session-cookies-params-request-in-model for more detail on how to do it.

-- edit --

There are several way to do it.

First one to cross my mind is that you add: `attr_accessor :request_language` to model, then pass `request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` from controller to model:

```
if @website.update_attributes(params[:website])
  @website.request_language = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
  # ...
```

and now you can proceed like you did before with few modifications:

```
def auto_language
    if self.language == "Automatic (by user's browser language)"
         self.language = full_language(self.request_language.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
    end
 end
```

Second way I can think of is to use before/after filters in controller to influence params before they are passed to model.

...

Comment: Krule, check my task and please tell what is better way ?

Comment: I was in stupid panic) I created after_filter in controllers and all worked))

Answer (score 1):

if you want to something update after create action but not update action then see example

```
# write in your model
after_create :xyz
def xyz
 ...
 ...
end
```

above method **xyz** call after create action. when update call then it will not call.

Comment: I want to make it after_update. How to make it only on update action ? In controller.

Comment: if you want make it both after_create & after_create then call that method as after_save :xyz . but if you want make it after_update then call as after_update :xyz

Comment: you can also call that method as before_save :xyz that work in both

Answer (score 0):

`request` object isn't available in models. You should do those tweaks on the controller layer.

```
def action
    if @model.language == "Automatic (by user's browser language)"
         @model.language = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
    end
    if @model.save
        ... 
    else
        ...
    end
end

private

def full_language
  ...
end
```

Comment: Have you placed your `full_language` method in your controller? See my updated answer. Also storing select-box values such `"Automatic (by user's browser language)"` in the database is terrible. You'd rather use language abbreviations or integers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of `:language` in the `params` hash, since that's what you're ultimately passing to `@website.update_attributes`. I would also suggest moving that conditional into the model layer to make your controller code more readable:

```
# app/controllers/websites_controller.rb
def update
  @website = Website.find(params[:id])
  if @website.language_automatic?
    params[:website][:language] = full_language(request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @website.update_attributes(params[:website])
      format.html { redirect_to @website, 
        notice: 'Note: code has been updated. Please replace the code you have on your website with the code below. Only then changes will take effect.'}
      format.js
    end
  end
end

# app/models/website.rb
def language_automatic?
  language == "Automatic (by user's browser language)"
end
```